# Extract element in column between two pipes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe such as :

```
COL1        
Cais_lupus|A0AYFFTBB6|AFTT1SZAA6_9VIRU
Rats|Q1GYHH9|VFG_IIV3
Mice|Q9TY15|Q9GT5_GQCPA
Bird|BTYG8|BHJU8_OUIVM
```

And I would like to extract into a new `COL2` the element in `COL1` beetwen the two pipes. And get:

```
COL1                                      COL2 
Cais_lupus|A0AYFFTBB6|AFTT1SZAA6_9VIRU    A0AYFFTBB6
Rats|Q1GYHH9|VFG_IIV3                     Q1GYHH9
Mice|Q9TY15|Q9GT5_GQCPA                   Q9TY15
Bird|BTYG8|BHJU8_OUIVM                    BTYG8
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: WHats happens if only one `|` ? Or three or more `|` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with escape `|`, because special regex character for get values between 2 `|`:

```
df['COL2'] = df['COL1'].str.extract('\|(.+)\|')
print (df)
                                     COL1        COL2
0  Cais_lupus|A0AYFFTBB6|AFTT1SZAA6_9VIRU  A0AYFFTBB6
1                   Rats|Q1GYHH9|VFG_IIV3     Q1GYHH9
2                 Mice|Q9TY15|Q9GT5_GQCPA      Q9TY15
3                  Bird|BTYG8|BHJU8_OUIVM       BTYG8
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `str.split` on `'|'` and select second element of each split:

```
df['COL2'] = df['COL1'].str.split('|').str[1]
```

Output:

```
                                     COL1        COL2
0  Cais_lupus|A0AYFFTBB6|AFTT1SZAA6_9VIRU  A0AYFFTBB6
1                   Rats|Q1GYHH9|VFG_IIV3     Q1GYHH9
2                 Mice|Q9TY15|Q9GT5_GQCPA      Q9TY15
3                  Bird|BTYG8|BHJU8_OUIVM       BTYG8
```

Comment: If only one `|` then it not return values between two `||`